# Не отображается изображение при выводе на интерфейс

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random

list_card = (#n-ое кол-во изображений)

rand_card = random.choice(list_card)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x300')
window.title('name')
icon = PhotoImage(file='name.png')
window.iconphoto(False, icon)
window.config(bg="#139832")

def rcard():
    image = PhotoImage(file=rand_card)
    s_image = image.subsample(4, 4)
    randcard = Label(window, image=s_image)
    randcard.place(x=100, y=200)


button1 = Button(window, text='random card',
                 command=rcard)


button1.place(x=175)
window.mainloop()
```

При таком коде, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, у меня появляется поле под изображение, но самого изображения как такового нет. Если я буду делать то же самое, но без функции и кнопки, то всё будет в норме.
Что я делаю не так и как исправить это?
Прилагается два фото (первое с функцией и кнопкой, второе без)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]